# Installing archlinux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, arch-linux, vmware-fusion

Hello I am trying to install arch linux on a virtual machine.

But when I import the iso and go through every step and get into the actual shell everything is ok but when I reboot the installation resets because I get the installation screen everytime and the OS is reset.. What do I have to do to avoid this and just start running the os

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When the virtual machine reboots, it boots from the CD again.

You need to remove the installation image (iso) after you install the system.

> Devices > CD/DVD Devices > Remove disk from virtual drive

Comment: I have tried this already but when rebooting I get the error no operating system found

Comment: that would likely mean grub/lilo is not installed properly